# Erlang/OTP, how to signal an application startup error without a crash

Tags: crash, erlang, erlang-otp

So I have this application that has a process that requires some gen_servers to be alive somewhere else in the cluster.
If they are up it just works, if they are not, my gen_server fails in init with `{error,Reason}`, this propagates through my supervisor into my applications `start` function.
The problem is that if I return anything other than {ok,Pid} I get a crash report.

My intention here would be to somehow signal that the application couldn't start properly and that all the processes are down and because of that the application should not be considered active, however, I can only choose to return {ok, self()} and see my application listed as `active` when it is not, or return {error, Error} and see how it crashes with:

```
{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},{ancestors,[rtb_sup,<0.134.0>]},
{messages,[]},{links,[<0.135.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,false},{status,running},
{heap_size,377},{stack_size,24},{reductions,255}],[]]:\n"
```

The problem seems to be bigger than this, basically there is no way to tell to the application framework that the app failed. It may look like one of these things that are handled by `let the process die` in erlang, but allow for an `{error, }` return value on `application:start` seems like a good tradeoff.

Any hints?

Comment: just curious: what would be the difference (for practical matters) between an application that couldn't start (it crashed), and an application that started but cant do anything? Would you do anything with your started (but failed) application, like polling when these gen_servers are up and then continue execution? What would be the point of "signalling" that your application could not start instead of letting it crash at startup? Maybe you would want to start your app but wait for an event from these gen_servers when they're up so you can continue execution

Comment: it is better to crash an application that keep it in some bizarre condition

Comment: I agree. It may even be better to create a dependency on the application that starts the other gen_server's, so everything is started in the right order

Comment: Couldn't the `Mod:start/2` function first check whether the necessary servers are running before starting the tree and if not return `{error,Reason}`. This would mean moving intelligence up out of the application servers which might be a bad thing.

Comment: @marcelog if the application is started but can't do anything(cause the processes weren't alive) it still shows in application:which_applications() which I use a lot on my management layer to check for started apps. If the application would not start I can always log it in my management layer and obviously show that it is not started.

Comment: @user425720 indeed, no bizarre state, I would prefer for it to be not started at all, like when a dependency is not running, it fails gracefully

Comment: @rvirding thats exactly the problem, Mod:start cannot fail, so even if I move the logic up there it cannot fail gracefully, it must return {ok, Something} and the system will consider the application to be running

Comment: @ArkaitzJimenez uhhmm.. So you would like to have an error message instead of a crash? how is an error message (and not starting the application) different from a crash?

Comment: @marcelog I do application:start(my_app), and what I get if it fails is {error, shutdown} and none of the relevant info like my exit message. Basically the caller gets nothing. In the other side, the error_handler module gets a crash report, completely out of band and disengaged from the code that tries to start the app.

Comment: Seems like you could benefit from this patch, which makes supervisors pass error reasons up the chain: https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/8d3a739adf0cafeb98784daaa280c5e05549ad60

Comment: @legoscia thanks, but it is not the supervisor problem, its the application/application_master/application_controller modules who won't give u back that information when you do `application:start(app)`

Answer (score 1):

Application will crash at any moment, so application's dependence relationship at the start time can not provide helpful dynamic crash information.

Before I have read part of `rabbitmq` project source code, it is also a cluster-based program.

I think `rabbitmq` has faced your similar question as you said, because cluster need collect related `nodes's` application "is live" information and `memory water highmark information` and then make decision.

It's solution is

1. to register the the first main process of the application in the node locally, the name is "rabbit" in the rabbitmq system, you can find it is `rabbit.erl` file, and in the function "start/2".

   `start(normal, []) ->
       case erts_version_check() of
           ok ->
               {ok, SupPid} = rabbit_sup:start_link(),
               true = register(rabbit, self()),
               print_banner(),
               [ok = run_boot_step(Step) || Step <- boot_steps()],
               io:format("~nbroker running~n"),
               {ok, SupPid};
           Error ->
               Error
       end.`
2. And the other 4 modules, `rabbit_node_monitor.erl, rabbit_memory_monitor.erl, 
   vm_memory_monitor.erl, rabbit_alarm.erl` to use two erlang technique, one is monitor process to get "DOWN" message of the registered process, the other is alarm handler to collect these information.